# Every Fourth Wormhole

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, grid-deduction, mazes, three-dimensional

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #33: Surface Geometry Mazes](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6011/2071)</sup>

---

[image: Instructions]

[image: Puzzle]

Comment: Whoever VTC 'unclear what you are asking' - its perfectly clear. The instructions are given, you just have to read them

Comment: To be fair, I don't really get it either, but a comment would have been sufficient. I personally would appreciate a clearly explained standalone step-by-step mini example.

Comment: White just means that the level is unknown, correct?  Some of the white tiles could be level 0.  Also, is the level threshold +2 to -1 or is it possible that there are levels above or below that in this puzzle?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil, if you think it's perfectly clear then please supplement the instructions with an unambiguous textual explanation.

Comment: Is O and X common or is it just from TGE's haisu?

Comment: I think I get the rules. The puzzle still seems very difficult!

Comment: @PeterTaylor instructionless/instruction-lite puzzles are actually quite popular. In the case of this puzzle, I don't think anything would be lost with clearer instructions, but I think it's clear enough as is.

Comment: Drats! Ran into a contradiction with the 4 and the 5. And it was all going so well, too :(

Comment: Looks like a great puzzle, but I've gotta agree with others above that the rules are pretty difficult to parse (though not to the point of "unclear what you are asking" IMO). Am I right in my interpretation, that you *must* turn *on* every circle (thus implying that circles on edges must be on changes in slope)? And further, that said turn must be *exactly one* turn (so you can't have a double slope change on a circle?) Also, it's not explicit, but I assume a 90° turn through a quadrilateral is "1 turn" and that you can't "cross over" a wormhole, and *must* teleport through it?

Comment: @Alconja you are correct about everything except that a crest or valley CAN contain a circle, on edge, which counts as one of the two turns.

Comment: @paramesis "Which counts as one of the two turns" - meaning the other turn can count as a turn either before or after the circle (at the solver's discretion)?

Comment: @Alconja correct, so long as the circles mark every fourth turn.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I'm not going to edit paramesis' post to do that, but you can ask him to do it. Or you can ask me to explain what I think we have to do in the instructions

Comment: @paramesis Can you please answer my question above?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @LeppyR64 you are correct, white tiles are at an undefined height and slope, which could be 0, and levels span from -1 to +2

Comment: @edderiofer Yes, there are exactly two wormholes per level

Comment: I think staring at this in 2D isn't cutting it, time for a print out! I can get so far but then I keep forgetting which position everything was in.

Comment: Exiting a sloped cell to a flat one count as 1 turn. Exiting a sloped cell into another sloped cell in the same ring counts as 0 turns. Exiting a sloped cell to a differently sloped cell in another ring counts as 2 turns (i.e. crossing a ridge or a valley). But, if you exit a sloped cell and enter another similarly sloped cell in an outer or inner ring (i.e. going uphill or downhill) counts as 0, 1 or 2 turns?

Comment: @VictorStafusa That would count as 0 turns.

Comment: Am I able to circle an entire triangleless flat ring without counting any turn?

Comment: @VictorStafusa Yes.  Going around a ring of trapezoids is equivalent to going in a straight line.  However, if you circled the ENTIRE ring, you would have an isolated loop, so the path has to turn at some point.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That was a fun maze!

Answer:

> [image: solved maze]
> I have colored the upward slopes red and the downward slopes green.

It would take too long to go through every step but it was possible to complete it without guessing. Here are some steps along the way:

> [image]
> [image]
> [image]
> [image]