# Nodes & Tunnels

Tags: visual, mazes

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #33: Surface Geometry Mazes](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6011/2071)</sup>

---

Behold, a tricky maze created on the surface of a cube. There are 'nodes' to collect and tunnels to traverse, are you up to the challenge?

> [image: Cube]

I have unfolded the cube and created a legend to aid your mission, you can also find the rules below! (Click images for a closer look):

> [image: RulesAndLegend]

Here is the maze in all it's unfolded glory, remember even in this condition it is still a cube!:

> [image: MazeUnfolded]

Answers should adhere to the above parameters, shown preferably with a nice long scrawl over my original image but feel free to improvise!

> There is at least one correct path but as with the nature of such a puzzle other solutions may exist. The first answer given that meets the criteria will be awarded the tick, if it's quite different to my solution I will also share mine as a second answer :)

Extra information for those that like to think out of the box, you can't jump walls, climb, fly, reach that node *just* over there, squeeze past your old paths, re-use tunnels or become a giant to take the whole maze and all it's nodes in one grab, etc ;)

EDIT: Quick rules clarification as a relative brought it up when attempting the puzzles, use of tunnels is optional. Whether completion is possible without them is another thing!

> **Good luck and I hope you have fun solving it!**

Comment: Few we didn't only have one question at the end of the fortnight (and here is 1k, grats! :) )

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Thank you, I've been working on the idea for about a week (sadly not as complex as Paramesis' amazing entry https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53145/every-fourth-wormhole) and finished with a couple of days to spare after triple checking my solution.

Comment: And I just realised I can't spell 'phew'

Comment: I knew what you meant ;)

Comment: Very stylish puzzle! Really nice looking. I like your tunnel innovation on the classic maze.

Comment: I will make a 3D Printable version of the cube maze available (with and without nodes) for anyone that would like a .stl, let me know and I'll upload to Thingiverse.

Comment: @Forklift Thank you, if this goes well I will have a go at something a bit more complex, multiple cubes (or other shapes) with 'bridges' perhaps?

Comment: I hope we aren't being chased by ghosts while doing this.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Wa-ka-wa-ka-wa-ka... (Not to confused with 'wocka-wocka' that's Fozzie Bear lol).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to work:

> [image]

Green is the path. Purple is showing how many times we enter each face.

Highly sophisticated method of solution: Trial and error. (I started by filling in things that were forced, then just drew stuff. I ended up with a couple of loops and some bits that wouldn't connect, and fixed things up incrementally.)

Comment: Wow awesome, some sections are just like mine but your overall route is different, quick work well done! :)

Answer (score 0):

As promised, here is my solution that was made when designing the maze:

> [image: Path]

I will probably make another in the near future as it was a fun process. For those wondering I used **Fusion360** to make the maze and **Clip Studio Paint** for the additional details.

> For the next maze I would like some suggestions and feedback if possible so please comment below or ping me on the chat.
>
> **A bigger cube?
>
>   A different shape?
>
>   Better layout/decorative details?
>
>   Bridges (maybe between multiple shapes)?
>
>   More restrictions/rules?
>
>   Non-Euclidean shapes?
>
>   Don't bother? ;)**

Comment: I like the bridges idea and also maybe a door/key combo where you need one before taking that path? Perhaps one way paths?

Comment: Fantastic ideas. If I use either I will be sure to credit you :)